# (discord.py) optimized help command

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a help command for my discord bot (written in python) that looks likes this:

```
@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx, cmd = None)

  if cmd == None
    [list of commands in an embed]

  elif cmd == example
    [info for example command]
```

The real thing has a lot of elif statements (one for every command). Up until now it worked fine until repl.it decided that i'm a terrible programmer and gave me this error:
`[mccabe] Cyclomatic complexity too high: 24 (threshold 15)`

I know that this means that my code is too complicated but i'm not exactly sure. The help command doesn't run at all now. I'm still pretty new to python and discord api so i would appreciate if anyone could teach me a better and more optimized way of doing the help command.

btw the above code was written in a cog with proper declarations and initializing.

Comment: You can use subcommands

Comment: what are those?

Answer (score 1):

You can use subcommands

```py
@bot.group()
async def help(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        # Send the initial embed

@help.command()
async def command1(ctx):
    # Send the help embed for this command

# To invoke
# !help
# -> initial embed
# !help command1
# -> embed for this command
```

An easier alternative is to simply subclass the default help command, take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/31a346ed1eb545ddeb0d451d81a60b3b) example

Answer (score 1):

Cyclomatic complexity means that you have to many branch (if, else) statement in you function. In that case the limit is 15 and you are at 24.

For your question maybe you should think having a dictionary with all the commands linked to their help. It's simple and reliable.

```
commands = {
    "first_command": "help message",
    "second_command": "help message",
    ...
}
```

Then in your code you can do this:

```
@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx, cmd = None)

  try:
      print(registry[cmd])
  except KeyError:
      print([cmd for cmd in registry.keys()])
```

That is just an example. If you know Object. You can replace the registry with a list of Command Object that contain the help and other information.

Comment: The answer below of Lukasz is maybe more related to discord api. I didn't know about subcommands but I guess it's more elegant and in respect with the framework